# How to reload js without "window." or "location."

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a js file. I need the js code to run like new every so seconds. It is not a website and I don't use "window". location.reload isn't working if I want to reload the js code alone.

I tried setInterval. It uses cached content. So I am not getting the accurate, current content. If I manually run my app, everytime I run my app, I get current content. But if I use setInterval, it only throws the same value that is loaded the first time. Are there any npm packages available that can do the trick or any other way to do it? Thanks for the help.

This is the code:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('demo.py');
var infy =[];
infy.length = 0;
var infyTBV; // Infy Total Buy Volume
// PythonShell.run('demo.py', function (err, results) {
//   if (err) throw err;
//   console.log(results);
// });
printinfy();

setInterval(function() { infyTBVfn(); }, 10000);

setInterval(function() { printinfy(); }, 10000);

function printinfy(){
pyshell.on('message', function (message){
    var mainstring = message.toString();
    // var substring = "totalBuyQuantity";
    infy.push(mainstring);
    // console.log("Inside loop: " + infy);
    // if(infy.includes("totalBuyQuantity")){
    //   infyTBV = message; 
    // }
});
}

function infyTBVfn(){

    var sno = 0;
        infy.forEach(function(element) {
    // console.log(sno+": "+element);
        if (sno == 63){
        infyTBV = element;
        console.log("outside loop: " + infyTBV);
    }
    sno++;
});
    // console.log("Number of items in var: "+infy.length);
}
```

I have another python file from where I'm reading the content. I'm getting the data from the python file using the 'printinfy' function.

I named this file as demo.js. When I run node demo.js, it provides different value everytime I run it(That's what I wanted). However, if I let it print out the value automatically using

> setInterval(function() { infyTBVfn(); }, 10000);

it prints the same value as the first time it printed.

Comment: If you change your code, then yes, you have to terminate the app and restart it. You can make your code read the contents of a file if you need "current content" (whatever you mean by that).

Comment: how do I terminate and start the app again?

Comment: can you please show us the code using `setinterval`?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I've added the details and code to the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Very unclear question.  You need to explain exactly what type of content in what type of file is being updated real-time.  Then, and only then, can we offer you solutions for reading that content in without restarting your node.js script.  You probably should have your python program put the data into a ***data*** file, not a JS file and then you can read the latest copy of the data file whenever you want.  You could use JSON as the data format if you want and use `JSON.parse()` to parse the data.  Then, you can read the latest copy of the file whenever you want.

Comment: Those are all what I don't understand. That's why I wanted to know if there is a way that node example.js function can be automated.

Comment: You shouldn’t only call pritify but also you should create new pythonshell every time, since it will run only once. I’ll do the code in few hours, if you’ll still need it.

Comment: Great. Plz help

Answer (score -1):

The best solution here is to add the timestamp at the end of the .js/.css filenames

```
<script src="js/myfile.js?t=<?=time()?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or For refresh Div you can use this Example

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var baseDate       = new Date(),
        seconds        = baseDate.getSeconds(),
        secondsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("seconds")[0];
    secondsElement.innerHTML = seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="seconds"></div>
```